# Advice manipulating text files using sed and awk

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Ive been playing with sed and awk but cant seem to get this working as expected. Im trying to take a textfile of firstname lastname perline and manipulate them to show firstname+lastname inital.

Ive achieved Last initial followed by firstname but cant get it the other way around ^_^ and help would be appreciated

```
cat /root/Desktop/Userlist.txt | awk '{ print $2, $1 }' | sed 's/\(.\).* /\1/g'
```

**EXAMPLE of whats expected**

```
John Smith
JohnS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ]+) ([^ ]).*$/\1\2/' /root/Desktop/Userlist.txt
```

No `cat`. `sed` is able to take input filenames as arguments.

Comment: Yes. @NeronLeVelu's answer is POSIX compliant. Mine uses the GNU-only `-r` option, which makes the regex a bit easier on the eyes and fingers.

Answer (score 1):

awk

```
$ echo "John Smith" | awk '{printf "%s%s\n", $1, substr($2,1,1)}'
JohnS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^\(.\)[^]* \{1,}\([^ ]\{1,}\).*/\2\1/' /root/Desktop/Userlist.txt
```

posix compliant